# When & where did the word "Christian" originate?

Tags: history

The word "Christian" very rarely used in the new testament to refer to those that trust/believe on Jesus.

Mostly they were simply called "believers".

When/where and by who coined the word "Christian"?

Comment: Could you add references to where you found "Mostly they were simply called "believers"."  As "believers" were also those in Judaism that did not believe Jesus to be the Messiah.  From my understanding.

Comment: i think the original use of the word was meant to identify "partisans of Christ" as opposed to partisans of someone else.

Comment: The word meaning "believer" in Greek would have been the participial form of the verb πιστεύω, πιστεύοντες (lit.. "the believing ones").  This does not occur in  a context signifying "believer" in the sense you suggest in a single verse of the New Testament.  There is not a single instance in the Bible where Christians are referred to as "believers".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the word Christian is used [three times](http://www.biblegateway.com/keyword/?version=KJV&search=Christian&searchtype=all&language1=en&spanbegin=1&spanend=73&resultspp=500&displayas=long&sort=bookorder) in the New Testament. The first occasion answers your question ([Acts 11:26c](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+11:26&version=NLT)):

> It was at Antioch that the believers were first called Christians.

Regarding ''how'' they came to be called Christians, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian#Early_usage) states:

> Kenneth Samuel Wuest holds that all three original New Testament verses' usages reflect a derisive element in the term Christian to refer to followers of Christ who did not acknowledge the emperor of Rome. The city of Antioch, where someone gave them the name Christians, had a reputation for coming up with such nicknames

Comment: Just beaten to it! +1

Comment: Good answer, but some of those verses cited in your "many times" link have absolutely no corresponding Greek word which can or should be translated as "Christian" (e.g., Rom. 16:16).

Comment: You're right.  But new living translation is not a literal translation so they have substituted some words not used.  If you use King James version which is literal you will want to look for the word 'Christianos'.  Therefore you could say the word "Christian" only appears 3 times.

Comment: Exactly. http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5546&t=KJV

Comment: The answer is good, so we should just edit that into it? Don't you think @Matt?

Comment: Probably.  I'm perhaps more interested in how "And the disciples were called Christians G5546 first in Antioch."... that part came about and who called them Christians.  I've heard from a source that I am unable to easily query that it came about from non-believers giving these Christ followers a name but wondered if anyone had any sources for that.

Comment: @Matt Perhaps you could edit that into your question. Currently it makes a false assertion anyway.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 - thanks, fixed (KJV)

Comment: @Matt - added a brief answer to your supplementary question in the comments, HTH.

Answer (score -1):

Those that believe the Book of Mormon to be the word of God, and a translation of ancient record, have reason to believe the term Christian predates New Testament times. In Alma 46:13 we find its first reference in the Book of Mormon, and an explanation of its use (my emphasis). This occurred around 73-72 BC in the Americas.

> [**Alma 46:13-15**](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/46.13-15?lang=eng#p12) - 13 [Moroni prays for liberty among the people] so long as there should a band of **Christians** remain to possess the land—
>
> 14 For thus were all the true believers of Christ, who belonged to the
>   church of God, called by those who did not belong to the church.
>
> 15 And those who did belong to the church were faithful; yea, all
>   those who were true believers in Christ took upon them, gladly, the
>   name of Christ, or Christians as they were called, because of their
>   belief in Christ who should come.

Interestingly enough the term seems to have a similar origin. In both cases it was used by those that did not believe in Christ to describe believers.

Comment: This gives insight not available in the bible of the origin of the term Christian. Any reason for the down vote? I would gladly clarify and discuss any point of my answer.